# Set install path using dpkg

Tags: debian, dpkg

I'd like to install some deb package
dpkg -i modeller_9.13-1_amd64.deb

consisted of some python modules. What frag should I provide to dpkg to set the install path during installation instead of default dir (on default to python dir(?

Thanks for help,

Gleb

Comment: Are you looking for `--root=...`? What are you trying to achieve by changing installation paths? Asking, because it tends to break things badly. Debian packages are not usually relocatable wrt. paths.

Comment: I just want to extract all data from package to the selected dir

Answer (score 10):

```
dpkg-deb -x $DEBFILE $TARGET_DIRECTORY
```

or if you don't have any debian tools at hand

```
ar p $DEBFILE data.tar.gz | tar -C $TARGET_DIRECTORY -xz
```

With more recent packages it might be `data.tar.xz` or something else though.